# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am new to React and I am having a problem.
How to iterate over an array in an array?
When trying to iterate over an array using the map() method, an error occurs

my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import Header from '../modules/header/header';
import Footer from '../modules/footer/footer';

import './pages.scss';

function PageWorksItem({ match, location }) {

    const { params: { id } } = match;
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [works, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let cleanupFunction = false;
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/works/${id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    if(!cleanupFunction) setItems(result);
                },
                (error) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setError(error);
                }
            )
            return () => cleanupFunction = true;
        }, [])

        if (error) {
            return <div className="works error">Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div className="works loading">. . .</div>;
        } else {
            return (
                <>
                    <Header />
                    <div className="works item">
                        {works.tags.map(item => (
                            <li>{item}</li>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <Footer />
                </>
            );
        }
    }

export default PageWorksItem;
```

JSON fragment:

```
{
    "works": [
        { 
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "21 one line SPA images",
            "cat": "Illustrations",
            "tags": ["one", "two", "free"]
        }
    ]
}
```

if you specify {works.tags} or with an index {works.tags[0]} - everything works, but if you iterate over the array, an error occurs.

Comment: Can you show result of `console.log(result);`?

Comment: `PageWorksItem` should return something!

Comment: @Viet
`{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "21 one line SPA images",
    "cat": "Illustrations",
    "tags": [
        "one",
        "two",
        "free"
    ]
}`

Comment: your `works` state is object it should be array in order to use map function.

Comment: what if you do spreadOperator: setItems({...result})?

Comment: You initialise `works` as an array but obviously your endpoint returns a single work item, which is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `works.tag.map`. But the initialization value of `works` is an empty array []:
`const [works, setItems] = useState([]);`. So `works.tag` is `undefined` and this error occurred.
You can fix this issue by add `optional chaining` like this:

```
{works.tags?.map((item, index)=> (
   <li key={index}>{item}</li>
))}
```

Note: You need to add unique `key` in child componet when using `map`

Comment: That's correct. OP should rename `works` to `work` as the endpoint only ever returns a single work and not a list of works. Also it should not be initialised as an array but probably with `null` or a default work object.